# Xamarin background color property

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I want to use AppThemeBinding and use a binding for both Dark and Light color. Here is the code I have:

`<Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={Binding onLigColour}, Dark={Binding someDarkColour}}"> <!-- ... --> </Grid>`

And a class that it binds to and retrieves those properties, here is a code that works:

`<Grid BackgroundColor="{onLigColour}"> <!-- ... --> </Grid>`

Can anyone tell me why binding in a AppThemeBinding does not work?

Comment: Are you using a binding or a StaticResource for the code that works ? You've forgotten to specify it : BackgroundColor="{onLigColour}"

Comment: {Binding  onLigColour} @Nk54

Answer (score 1):

We could not binding a value for `AppThemeBinding`.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={Binding onLigColour}, Dark={Binding someDarkColour}}">
```

Because the Light and Dork of `AppThemeBinding` is not bindable.

[image]

The bindable property looks like below.

[image]

You could use the color directly.

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#F1E1FF, Dark=#6C6C6C}">
```

Or you could use the static resource.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Background_Dark}, Light={StaticResource Background_Light}}">
```